# Different layout for controller with respond_to in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, erb

I understand I can call the `render` method with `layout: 'my_layout'` to change the layout within a controller method. However, some of my controller methods have the following so that I can easily render JSON as well:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render json: @cars }
end
```

How do I change the layout for `format.html`? Should I replace `format.html` with `render layout: 'my_layout'`? Is there an option I can pass to `format.html`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default Rails will use `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` as the layout.  If you want to use another layout, create `app/views/layouts/my-new-layout.html.erb` then

**In your controller method:**

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render layout: 'my-new-layout' }
  format.json { render json: @cars }
end
```

Here's the relevant section in the Rails Guide: [Layouts and Rendering: Options for Render](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#options-for-render)